# What's the precision of a GPS depending on the number of satellites?

Tags: gps, precision

I know that the precision of the GPS depends a lot on the quality of it but if you know aproximatively the precision of a GPS tracking depending on the number of satellites I would be very thankful.

Comment: Hi Carlos. This site is for questions related to programming. Check out [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/), which is much more suited to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of satellites has a counterituitivly low impact on GPS precision.

- On a theoretical basis, 3 Satellites will provide a perfect fix, in reality it will create a pyramid-shaped area of confidence space, that when projected onto a Map will be an error triangle.
- More satellites will add more facettes to the confidence space, but after projection onto a 2D map this will give only a modes reduction of error area.
- The biggest benefit of more satellites is the possibility to discard outliers - this is especially true in built-up areas where a reflected signal can create a wildly wrong area with a high confidence. If you have, say, 5 satellites with 4 agreeing well and one outlier, you have a good argument to discard it.

This works out to a situation with 4 satellites and good signal providing a much better fix than 7 satellites with bad signal.